# Consultar un registro que esté entre un rango de fechas en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Quiero mostrar un registro comparando la fecha de hoy con un rango ya establecido. Es decir, en mi registro hay una fecha inicio y una fecha final.

Quiero que el registro se muestre siempre y cuanto cumpla que la fecha de hoy se encuentre entre la fecha inicio y fecha final de mi registro.

Comment: Qué pasa con los registros que todavía están *vigentes*?, tienes puesta un valor en el futuro para la fecha final, o es la fecha final `null`?

Comment: creo que no me explique bien, te dare un ejemplo: tengo un registro con fecha de inicio 11/15/16 y fecha fin 1/17/16, hoy  que es dia 15 hago la consulta y se muestra el registro lo mismo asa el dia 16 y 17, sin embargo el dia 18 ya no deberia de mostrarse

Comment: Eso lo entendí, lo que estaba preguntando es si todos los registros tienen una fecha fin asignada, o puede haber valores `NULL` para la fecha de fin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías principalmente utilizar la [función `BETWEEN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx) y la [función `GETDATE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx).

Código:

```
Select * from tu tabla where GETDATE between fecharegistroinicio and fecharegistrofinal
```